# integrate/pracma::integral alternative

Tags: r, performance, numerical-integration

I don't really have any toy example but I was wondering if there is any alternative function to integrate or pracma::integral in R that is a bit quicker or if there is any way of speeding up any of the two. It is taking a while computing it and, although I expect it to take a while since it a lot of numerical computations are performed before, I'd hope for a quicker possibility if possible.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need an exact solution or rather an estimation?

Comment: `integrate` has some optional parameters that you could experiment with. Evaluate `?integrate` for details.

Comment: @JohnColeman I tried playing with the tolerance and subdivisions but I don't know what else to work with, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Onyambu ideally an exact solution but that's not possible with the nature of my problem. I would although like to have an estimation with a good accuracy

Comment: I suggest working on speeding up the function you are trying to integrate. Profiling would likely help (e.g, the `profvis` package).

Comment: We probably can't offer very concrete advice without a [mcve]. There's also the `cubature` package, but I think the fundamental problem is probably that your integrand has to be called many times to achieve adequate precision?